# Valgrind i can't really find the non init?

Tags: c, valgrind

I really can't find this basic error, i beginning into c and i don't really know how to use valgrind...

```
static  size_t  ft_intstrlen(int n)
{
        size_t  len;

        len = 0;
        if (n <= 0)
                len++;
        while (n)
        {
                n /= 10;
                len++;
        }
        return (len);
}

char    *ft_itoa(int n)
{
        char    *p_o;   
        size_t  len_n;

        len_n = ft_intstrlen(n);
        p_o = malloc((len_n + 1) * sizeof(char));
        if (p_o == NULL)
                return (NULL);
        if (n < 0) 
        {
                if (n == -2147483648)
                {
                        ft_strlcpy(p_o, "-2147483648", 12);
                        return (p_o);
                }
                *p_o = '-'; 
                n *= -1;
        }
        p_o[len_n] = '\0';
        while (len_n--)
        {
                if (p_o[len_n] != '-')
                        p_o[len_n] = (n % 10) + '0';
                n /= 10;
        }
        return (p_o);
}
```

> ==402191== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
> ==402191==    at 0x4054CD: ft_itoa (in /home/Documents/a.out)
> ==402191==    by 0x404BA7: main (ft_itoa_test.cpp:28)
> ==402191==
> 5.OK 6.MOK ==402191== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
> ==402191==    at 0x4054CD: ft_itoa (in /home/Documents/a.out)
> ==402191==    by 0x404C92: main (ft_itoa_test.cpp:32)
> ==402191==

```
    int main(void)
{
        signal(SIGSEGV, sigsegv);
        title("ft_itoa\t\t: ")

        char * s = ft_itoa(INT_MAX);
        /* 1 */ check(!strcmp(s, to_string(INT_MAX).c_str()));
        /* 2 */ mcheck(s, strlen(to_string(INT_MAX).c_str()) + 1); free(s); showLeaks();

        s = ft_itoa(INT_MIN);
        /* 3 */ check(!strcmp(s, to_string(INT_MIN).c_str()));
        /* 4 */ mcheck(s, strlen(to_string(INT_MIN).c_str()) + 1); free(s); showLeaks();

        s = ft_itoa(0);
        /* 5 */ check(!strcmp(s, to_string(0).c_str()));
        /* 6 */ mcheck(s, strlen(to_string(0).c_str()) + 1); free(s); showLeaks();

        s = ft_itoa(42);
        /* 7 */ check(!strcmp(s, to_string(42).c_str()));
        /* 8 */ mcheck(s, strlen(to_string(42).c_str()) + 1); free(s); showLeaks();
        write(1, "\n", 1);
        return (0);
}
```

Comment: This is C++ code not C code.

Comment: Compile your code with debugging info (`-g` if using gcc/g++). So that valgrind can give you exact code line numbers.

Comment: valgrind may be pointing to this line: `if (p_o[len_n] != '-')`. At that point `po[len_n]` has not been set to any value. Note that `malloc` does not initialised the allocated memory to any value.

Comment: Yeah the mem tester is a cpp but the ft_itoa is c, and acually i was that line that cause problem, i can't figure out how to solve it, you have an advice ?

Comment: `p_o = calloc((len_n + 1) , sizeof(char));`

Comment: Really thank a lot, is was stupid but make me crazy it's was a really simple fix, thx <3 <3

Comment: @kirjosieppo `sizeof (char)` is defined as `1` so `sizeof (char)` should be replaced with `1` in `calloc()` and omitted altogether in `malloc()`., e.g. `p_o = calloc (len_n + 1, 1);`. Which should itself be `if ((p_o = calloc (len_n + 1, 1)) == NULL) { /* handle error */ }`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Yes, I know. Maybe I was simply a bit lazy writing the comment.

Comment: No worries -- happens ... `:)`